# not able to parse the JSON using JSON decoder

Tags: ios, swift, ccavenue

I am new to swift and i am trying to integrate the CCAvenue payment gateway. I am hitting the server to get the payment option list from the CCAvenue server which i an getting in the response but i am not able to parse the data into a JSON object, it is throwing some exception. Thanks in advance for the help

here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let urlAsString = "https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?"

        let myRequestString = "command=\(COMMAND)&currency=\(currency)&amount=\(amount)&access_code=\(accessCode)&customer_identifier=\(customerIdentifier)"
        let myRequestData = NSData.init(bytes: myRequestString.cString(using: .utf8), length: myRequestString.count) as Data
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(url: URL(string: urlAsString)!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.setValue(urlAsString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
        request.setValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = myRequestData

        let requestData = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            let responseData = NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)

            if error == nil {
                print("\(responseData)")
            }

            // if request is error free then decode the json using json decoder and assigning the values to the array
            guard let data = data  else {return}
            do{
               let a = try JSONDecoder().decode([CCPaymentOption].self, from: data)

                print("\(String(describing: a))")
            }catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            }.resume()

        print("\(requestData)")
    }
```

this is what i am getting in my debugger

```
Optional({"payOptions":[{"payOpt":"OPTCRDC","payOptDesc":"Credit Card","cardsList":"[{\"cardName\":\"Diners Club\",\"cardType\":\"CRDC\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTCRDC\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Credit Card\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\"},{\"cardName\":\"MasterCard\",\"cardType\":\"CRDC\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTCRDC\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Credit Card\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\",\"statusMessage\":\"\"},{\"cardName\":\"Visa\",\"cardType\":\"CRDC\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTCRDC\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Credit Card\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\"}]"},{"payOpt":"OPTDBCRD","payOptDesc":"Debit Card","cardsList":"[{\"cardName\":\"MasterCard Debit Card\",\"cardType\":\"DBCRD\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTDBCRD\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Debit Card\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\"},{\"cardName\":\"Visa Debit Card\",\"cardType\":\"DBCRD\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTDBCRD\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Debit Card\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\"}]"},{"payOpt":"OPTNBK","payOptDesc":"Net Banking","cardsList":"[{\"cardName\":\"AvenuesTest\",\"cardType\":\"NBK\",\"payOptType\":\"OPTNBK\",\"payOptDesc\":\"Net Banking\",\"dataAcceptedAt\":\"CCAvenue\",\"status\":\"ACTI\",\"statusMessage\":\"\"}]"}]})
```

Error

Comment: If your code is throwing an exception and you need help, the best bet would be to include that exception in your question. I'd suggest you put a breakpoint in the catch loop share with us the error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are many points needed to be checked while decoding the object.**

1. Make sure your CCPaymentOption Model **addopt** the Protocol **Codable**.
2. While Decoding the Data , make sure you are **aware** of thing that your response is in form of **Dictionary** or **Array**
3. lets say you are getting the **Array** in response , in that case you can directly use [**CCPaymentOption]** in J**SONDecoder().decode() method.**
4. And if you are getting the **Dictionary** from the server response then **you need to decode the object on that way.**

**Example** of CCPaymentOption Model for point no ***3***.

```
struct CCPaymentOption : Codable {
    var amount:String  // Note down that , please use exact same 
                       // key as you are getting from server side.
}

do {

       let arrPaymentOptions = try JSONDecoder().decode([CCPaymentOption].self, from: responseData)

               print(arrPaymentOptions)
               ///... Array of Your Model reference.

    } catch {
               print(error)
            }
```

**Example** of CCPaymentOption Model for point no ***4***.

```
struct CCPaymentOption : Codable {
    var amount:String
}

struct responseDictionary : Codable {
    var paymentOption:[CCPaymentOption] // Note down that , please 
                                        // use exact same key as you 
                                        // are getting from server 
                                        // side.
}

do {

        let responseDict = try JSONDecoder().decode(responseDictionary.self, from: responseData)

               print(responseDict.paymentOption)
               // responseDict.paymentOption is the Array of Your 
               // Model reference.

    } catch {
               print(error)
            }
```

***Please try out the below one if you don't want to use the JSON decoder. :-***

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    guard error == nil else { return }
                    guard let responseData = data else { return }

                    do {

                        if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                            ///... All you want is here  jsonObject is the Dictionary (required , not an optional)  
                        }

                    } catch  {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }).resume()
```

After getting the data from server side , you need to do **JSONSerialization** with the help of native method. This method will **return** the **Dictionary** or **Array** (**Depending** on your **server** **response**.)

Comment: happy to help you @Rishabh.t .

Comment: @GOPALVASANI & @Rishabh.t : Just wanted to let you both know that this answer has nothing to do with `JSONDecoder`. `JSONSerialization` will convert a json to a dictionary/array whereas `JSONDecoder` would convert the json to your `CCPaymentOption` model object.

Comment: @staticVoidMan , i know that , even objectMapper is used to mapping the data to our model class .

Comment: @GOPALVASANI ok but you do realize this question is about `JSONDecoder` and the OP is using a `CCPaymentOption` model. If you are providing an alternative solution then mention that in your answer or this dude is gonna come back and ask why his `CCPaymentOption` model is not working.

Comment: yes @staticVoidMan , ok let me update the answer with the help of Json decoder or without it.

Comment: the json decoder one is not working i am getting the same result

Comment: @Rishabh.t , above answer is perfectly working and right in both ways (with JSON decoder and without it) . you need to check some points as your sever response is Array or Dictionary ? you need to decode the JSON on that way , make sure your model CCPaymentOption has a same properties with same DataType as you have recieved from response .

Comment: struct CCPaymentOption: Decodable {
    var payOptions: String
}

Comment: here is my ccPaymentOption

Comment: @Rishabh.t , Please debug your code , are you able to print out the those statement :- print("\(String(describing: a))") ???

Comment: no its going to the catch block and printing the error message

Comment: @Rishabh.t , print out the error in catch block and let me know what it says.

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x101bf07e8) to 'CCPaymentOption'

Comment: @Rishabh.t , i have updated the my answer , its helps you a lot . please read it carefully.